# python library for large tab/comma delimited text file

Tags: python

I have some big genomic data files to analyze, which come in two forms, one individual dosage file like this:

```
id                      snp1    snp2    snp3    snp4    snp5    snp6
RS1->1000001    DOSE    1.994   1.998   1.998   1.998   1.830   1.335
RS1->1000002    DOSE    1.291   1.998   1.998   1.998   1.830   1.335
RS1->100001     DOSE    1.992   1.998   1.998   1.998   1.830   1.335
RS1->100002     DOSE    1.394   1.998   1.998   1.998   1.830   1.335
RS1->10001      DOSE    1.994   1.998   1.998   1.998   1.830   1.335
RS1->1001001    DOSE    1.904   1.998   1.998   1.998   1.830   1.335
RS1->1002001    DOSE    1.094   1.998   1.998   1.998   1.830   1.335
RS1->1003001    DOSE    1.994   1.998   1.998   1.998   1.830   1.335
RS1->1004001    DOSE    1.994   1.998   1.998   1.998   1.830   1.335
RS1->1005002    DOSE    1.994   1.998   1.998   1.998   1.830   1.335
```

The other contains some summary info:

```
SNP         Al1 Al2 Freq1   MAF     Quality Rsq 
22_16050607 G   A   0.99699 0.00301 0.99699 0.00000
22_16050650 C   T   0.99900 0.00100 0.99900 0.00000
22_16051065 G   A   0.99900 0.00100 0.99900 0.00000
22_16051134 A   G   0.99900 0.00100 0.99900 0.00000
rs62224609  T   C   0.91483 0.08517 0.91483 -0.00000
rs62224610  G   C   0.66733 0.33267 0.66733 0.00000
22_16051477 C   A   0.99399 0.00601 0.99399 -0.00000
22_16051493 G   A   0.99900 0.00100 0.99900 -0.00000
22_16051497 A   G   0.64529 0.35471 0.64529 0.00000
```

The SNP column in the second file corresponds the snp1, snp2... in the first file. I need to use the summary info in the second file to do some quality check and selection, then apply some statistical analysis on the data in the first file accordingly.

The question is, is there a python library suitable for this task? Performance is vital here, because these are really huge files. Thanks!

Comment: How big is "really huge"?

Comment: I have given you a great module for this in my answer, but if you're more specific on what you need to do from file to file with your check and selection, I can update my answer accordingly!

Comment: @mgilson Millions of columns and thousands of rows.

Answer (score 2):

For dealing with large files and data with high performance and efficient manipulation, there is really no better module than [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

The following code will read your file into a `DataFrame` and allow easy manipulation:

```
import pandas as pd
data = 'my_data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

now `df` is an efficient dataframe containing your data! Also, you don't even need to say it's tab delimiter because pandas "sniffs" for the delimiter

Comment: As mentioned by @mgilson in his answer, a database is also a viable option, how do you compare that with pandas? Thanks!

Comment: are you asking me how it compares with pandas or was that a statement? haha I can't tell

Comment: :), I mean how it compares with pandas.

Answer (score 1):

There is the `csv` module.  It's written with a `C` backend, so it should perform pretty well.  That said, `str.split` might be even *faster* if the format is simple enough.

It seems to me that rather than using a CSV file to store the data, some sort of database is probably an even better bet.

Comment: Which one do you think is better, pandas or a database? Can you provide a comparison? Thanks!